# For any given alphabet $\Sigma$, find the language $L$ that satisfies $L = (\Sigma L)^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, formal-languages

I have an exercise and I don't know how to solve it. The problem statement is as follows:

Prove, for any alphabet $\Sigma$, there is a unique language $L$ that satisfies $L = (\Sigma L)^C$. What language is it?

From set theory I know that $A^C = U - A$, therefore $(\Sigma L)^C = \Sigma^* - \Sigma L$ (where $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all words over an alphabet $\Sigma$) .
I can't think of anything that can help me here using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $(\Sigma L)^c = L$ can also be written, by taking complements on both sides, as $\Sigma L = L^c$. It follows that, for every word $u \in \Sigma^*$ and every letter $a \in \Sigma$,
$$
u \in L \iff au \in L^c \quad (1)
$$
Indeed, if $u \in L$, then $au \in \Sigma L = L^c$ and if $au \in L^c = \Sigma L$, then $u \in L$.

Now, since $\Sigma L$ does not contain the empty word $\varepsilon$, one must have $\varepsilon \in L$. Using (1), it is now easy to prove (by induction on the length of the words) that the words of even length are  necessarily in $L$, and those of odd length are necessarily in $L^c$. It follows that $L$ is necessarily equal to the language $(\Sigma^2)^*$ of words of even length. It just remains to verify that indeed, this language is a solution of the equation $\Sigma L = L^c$.

Comment: When you said "every letter $a \in A$ ".
Is $A$ the alphabet $\Sigma $ (i.e. $A = \Sigma$)?

Comment: Arghhh... Corrected. I normally use the letter $A$ for the alphabet. This is easy to remember ($A$ as **A**lphabet) and easier to type than $\Sigma$;

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the length words induction? With the base case of induction I have no problem, but with the inductive step I see it more or less clear, but I don't know how to formalize it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main trick for this induction is to observe that $u \in L \iff au\in L^c$ also gives $u \in L^c \iff au \in L$. Can you see why?

Comment: I think I see that, if you have a word $u \in L$ and you add any letter $a$ from alphabet $\Sigma$ in front, then $au$ it's not in $L$, but it's contained in his complementary $L^C$ and vice versa.

Comment: In fact, when you have $P \iff Q$, you also have $\text{not} P \iff \text{not} Q$. Do you see how to proceed for the induction now?

Answer (score 0):

A word $w\in\Sigma^*$ is in $(\Sigma L)^C$ iff it is not of the form $\alpha u$ for any $\alpha\in\Sigma$ and $u\in L$. Since we want to have $L=(\Sigma L)^C$, we want an $L$ such that $w\in L$ iff $w\ne\alpha u$ for any $\alpha\in\Sigma$ and $u\in L$. In other words, $L$ must contain $\epsilon$, since that is clearly not of the form $\alpha u$, and the non-empty words in $L$ must have the form $\alpha u$ for some $\alpha\in\Sigma$ and $u\notin L$: if $\epsilon\ne w\in\Sigma^*$, then $w\in L$ iff peeling off the first character of $w$ leaves a word **not** in $L$. This means that $L$ should satisfy the equation

$$L=\{\epsilon\}\cup\Sigma\left(L^C\right)\,.$$

Suppose that $L$ is such a language.

- Show that $\Sigma\cap L=\varnothing$, so that $\Sigma\subseteq L^C$.
- Show that $L=\{w\in\Sigma^*:|w|\text{ is even}\}$.

When you’ve done this, you’ll have shown that there is at least one such language, but you’ll still have to prove that it’s unique. HINT: If $L'\ne L$ is another such language, consider a $w\in L'\setminus L$ of minimal length.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed explanation! I can't quite see the step from the equation $L = \{ ϵ \} \cup \Sigma  (L^C)$ to demonstrate those 2 premises.

Comment: @csstudent229: The first is immediate: if a word consists of a single letter $\alpha$, removing that letter leaves the empty word, which **is** in $L$, so $\alpha$ cannot be in $L$. The second can be done by induction on $|w|$.

Comment: I think I have explained myself wrong, my fault. What I wanted to say is that I don't see the relationship of the equation $L = \{ ϵ \} \cup \Sigma (L)^C$ with those 2 premises. What do they have to do with the equation? Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: @csstudent229: They’re conclusions, not premises, and the equation is what you need in order to prove them. Or rather, the equation is a concise description of the fact that you need, which in turn was set out at more length in the paragraph leading up to the equation. It is precisely the fact that $L$ consists of the empty word and the words obtained by prefixing one letter to words **not** in $L$ that lets you prove those two facts. I used (part of) it in my previous comment proving the first bullet point.